# splitting a string into a list in specman

Tags: list, split, specman

Supposing I have a string:

```
str = “ab,cd,ef”
```

and I want to split it into a list

```
lst = [“ab”,”cd”,ef”]
```

How can I do it best, assuming that I don’t know ahead of time how many items are in the string?

---

Basically I'm looking for a specman equivalent to Perl's:

```
$str = "ab,cd,ef";
@lst = split /,/, $str;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

str_split is what you want.

From Specman 6.1 docs:

```
str_split(str: string, regular-exp: string): list of string
```

Syntax Example

```
var s: list of string = str_split("first-second-third", "-");
```